# Can you help me access Mac SMB share from Ubuntu using smbclient? (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED error)

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, smb

I've been working on a file server product that uses smbcilent to transfer files between client computers and the server. It's been working great so far with our LAMP (Ubuntu) server and Windows machines.

I'm currently trying to expand the setup to include Mac's, but am having trouble with the server accessing the share on the Mac.

Here's my command and error (bracketed descriptions replace private info):

```
# smbclient //10.101.0.7/[share-file] -U [username]%[password] -c ls
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
NTLMSSP packet check failed due to short signature (0 bytes)!
NTLMSSP NTLM2 packet check failed due to invalid signature!
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Things I've tried:

✓ Accessing share using a Windows machine to ensure the share is setup properly - check! Works fine there.

✓ Invoking `-S off` or `--signing=off` in the command - no change.

✓ Just looking at the shares first using `smbclient -L 10.101.0.7 -U [username]%[password]` - same error.

✓ Googling for an answer - check! Several people with similar problems, but no working solutions so far.

The most promising thing I've see so far involves compiling smbclient 4.4 from sources and running that with no authentication (`-U ""%""`), but that seems like a temporary solution based on a bug rather than a solid plan that will work for a long time. (But I'll try that next if I can't find any better ideas...)

Thanks for reading and trying to help!

Comment: Have the same problem. Looks like the same as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1711212

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `--option="ntlmssp_client:force_old_spnego = yes"` to the `smbclient` command as [suggested on the samba-technical](http://samba.2283325.n4.nabble.com/ntlmssp-errors-against-El-Capitan-s-SMB-Server-tp4706666p4707237.html) mailing list.

For me, this now lists shares on a Mac OSX server:

```
smbclient -U$user%$password -L $mac_host --option="ntlmssp_client:force_old_spnego = yes"
```

For mounting, you may need to add the `nounix,sec=ntlmssp` options as in

```
sudo mount -t cifs //$mac_host/$share $mountpoint -o nounix,sec=ntlmssp,username=$user,password=$password
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's been a while since I worked on this particular issue, but I believe I tried an option with "spnego" in it to no avail. Not sure if it was exactly the same as what you suggested, but I remember that word. (And I don't currently have access to the code to check.) Either way, I'll keep it in mind for when I'm working on that project again.

Answer (score 1):

On recent versions of MacOS (e.g. Monterey) it is necessary to do several configuration steps to enable smb access from Linux:

1. Open `System Preferences`.
2. Select `Sharing`.
3. Select `File Sharing`.
4. Ensure that the directory is listed in `Shared Folders`.
5. Right-click/two-finger click on the share directory.
6. Click on `Advanced Options`
7. Ensure `Only allow SMB encrypted connections` is checked.
8. Click `OK`
9. Click on `Options`
10. Click on the checkbox for `Share files and folders using SMB`.
11. Under `Windows File Sharing` ensure the appropriate user is checked.
12. Type the *user*'s password in the 'Authenticate' dialog bo and press 'OK'.
13. Click 'Done'.

You should now be able to connect from Linux to the MacOS share using the commands given by @mivk.